# I am connecting my Java program using hibernate to mysql database but getting error

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1396)
    at com.telusko.DemoHibb.App.main(App.java:24)
```

My Hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/neon</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: you give way to little context for us to even begin guessing what's going wrong.

Comment: It sounds like your mysql server is not running.

Comment: my sql server is running .The problem was with compatibility of mysql connectors and between java hibernate.There is actually a bug in that version of java.

Comment: After a lot of efford I am able to find the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with compatibility of older versions of MySQL Connector/J with MySQL 8. Simply I have to upgrade the SQL Connector version with latest versions.

After a lot of efforts I am able to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check your MySQL-server is running:

**For Unix** (sh):

```
sudo netstat -npl | grep 3306
```

**For Windows** (cmd):

```
netstat -aon | find /i "3306"
```

If empty than *run MySQL-server* or *change port*